# TagHelper get MaxLengthAttribute attribute from ForExpression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

How can I get the MaxLength attribute from within the TagHelper ModelExpression?

I used to be able to do this in MVC 5

```
var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;

var maxLength = member?.Member
    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MaxLengthAttribute), false)
    .FirstOrDefault() as MaxLengthAttribute;
```

I need to get the MaxLength attribute that is on the Model - Example:

```
[MaxLength(5)]
[Display(Name = "First Name")]
public string FirstName { get; set; }
```

The TagHelper does expose the ModelExpression.Metadata.**DisplayName** attribute and others, but not the MaxLength or the StringLength attributes

Comment: You're trying to access the value of the `MaxLength` attribute on a given property on your server, right?

Comment: Yes, access the attribute and the value

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to get any Validator Metadata:

ForExpression variable is set to ModelExpression via the HtmlAttributeName

```
    [HtmlAttributeName("for")]
    public ModelExpression ForExpression { get; set; }
```

Then use PropertyAttributes collection to get the desired property

```
var maxLengthAttribute = ForExpression.Metadata.ValidatorMetadata.OfType<MaxLengthAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Modified to avoid reflection, see ([Exposing model attributes](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4597))

Comment: Thank you very much! I've already broken my whole brain))